# Swift - Change background color of tab bar icons like Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, instagram, uicolor

I'd like to customize the appearance of a tabBar. I'd like to recreate the look on the Instagram app, for those unfamiliar with the tab bar in that app, see this image: [Instagram Tab Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qlym.jpg). This is my current tab bar: [Current Tab Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewdtI.jpg).

I've got the background color set and the position of the images but I'd like the selected tab bar icon to have a darker background color to the rest of them. Also, I'd like the center tab bar icon to be a different color regardless of whether or not it's selected.

To clarify, I just need the code to change the background color of a tab bar icon when selected and not selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583693/how-to-change-tint-color-of-tab-bar-in-swift/33587568#33587568

Comment: Awesome, thanks @alex_p! Do you know how I can now get the central button to be a different colour no matter if it's selected or not as seen in Instagram's tab bar?

Comment: Try to use first `extention` from answer like `tabBar!.items![2].image = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize` with color you need

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work... This is my code:
`tabBar!.items![2].image = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar!.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar!.items!.count), tabBar!.frame.height))` @alex_p

Comment: All this is doing is making the central button grey and the icon isn't visible as it's the same colour as the background @alex_p

Comment: Yes, my mistake. You need to create custom background for tabBar with rect on center. Need to add it to first extantion for example to create custom image and then set it image to tabBar background

Comment: Ok, got it. After a bit of messing around I got it! Thanks for your help @alex_p

Comment: @SebVidal - How did you manage to get the central tab item with a different colour? Can you provide the code?

Comment: @shivamkaushik Sure, here's what I use...
`let itemWidth = tabBar!.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar!.items!.count)`
`let size : CGFloat = CGFloat(itemWidth) * CGFloat(2)`
`let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(size, 0, itemWidth, tabBar!.frame.height))`
`bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex:0x015187)
        tabBar!.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: 2)`
Sorry for the delay!

Comment: Works great.Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem, take take :) @shivamkaushik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had create a subclass of UITabBarController and in the viewDidLoad add this:

```
let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let size : CGFloat = CGFloat(itemWidth) * CGFloat(2)
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(size, 5, itemWidth-10, tabBar.frame.height-10))
let image = UIImage(named: "compose")
imageView.image = image
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
tabBar.insertSubview(imageView, atIndex: 2)
```

I just used an image with the background color that i wanted.
That is how it's looks like: [image: TabBar]

Hope this could help!