# change inactive color of the tab item

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I was able to change the active color of my tab bar using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard?answertab=active#tab-top)

[image: chage color inactive tab bar]

My problem is that I don't know how to change the inactive ones like the friends and search tab. I want to change it something like red.

Comment: possibly duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583693/how-to-change-tint-color-of-tab-bar-in-swift/33587568#33587568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I have created two images for each icon.

Home Icon, Friends Icon and Search Icon each has white and green color.
[image: inactive tabbar icon]

Then clicking **`Assets.xcassets`** file to add **`New Image Set`**
[image: New Image Set]

Making it sure that the green icons  **`Render As`** is set to **`Original Image`** **since this will be the inactive color icon of our tab bar**.Here is a sample screen shots for the sample attribute
[image: Render As Original Image]

By setting the Home Item tab bar Icon. Please Note

```
System Item => Custom
Selected Image => Home_w//Name of the home white icon
Title => Home
Image=> Home_g//Name of the Inactive tabbar item in my case are sets to green icons
```

[image]

finally overriding Title Color of our tab bar items in **`AppDelegate.swift`**.Please note i have used [**`UIColor_Hex_Swift`**](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift) for hex UIColor.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    let color:UIColor =  UIColor(rgba: "#026a34") //UIColor(hexString:"026a34")
    
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color], forState: .Normal)
    
    // then if StateSelected should be different, you should add this code
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Selected)
    
    return true
}
```

Out put(White ones are the selected Image and green ones are the inactive image)

[image: Home active]
[image: Friends active]
[image: search active]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property `Render As` of your tab bar images within your asset catalog directly. There you have the option to set the property to `Default`, `Original Image` and `Template Image`.

[image]

Comment: where could i find asset catalog?I really dont know about it because i new to ios development

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 10 you can use this to change the tab item colors (you have to have the images rendering as templates):

```
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .blue
    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .gray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 self.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Can you explain more? where will i put that code?I know I was able to change tintcolor without using any code.my problem is the inactive ones , the search and the friends tab item.

Comment: Subclass  UITabBarController set class. and write in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767098/how-to-change-inactive-icon-text-color-on-tab-bar) is the best link you wish to search for your concrete solution.